# Bootstrap 3 on Rails 4 Button on nav collapse doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I`m having problem with the button when bootstrap collapse the nav, the button with the 3 strips won't work.

Using Rails 4.0.2, Bootstrap 3

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "WorkIt", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to "Clients", clients_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Orders", orders_path %></li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li><p class="navbar-text"><%= current_user.email %></p></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
        <li><p class="navbar-text">You are not signed in.</p></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

---

Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>WorkTiagotscha</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
    <%= render "layouts/nav" %>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
      <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    <%= yield %>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

I found out that the dropdown is working that is why there is a test dropdown there.

I used most of solutions that i could find about dropdown not working on rails, but i think the problem is only the button, might be a small thing but I ran out of options.

Bootstrap.js is not repeting, not rake assets:clean works.

Comment: Did you add `meta` tags to your code ? Check this link for more info http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: @KienThanh `meta` tag was not the issue. He put wrong `id` in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `#` from the Id attribute

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

Should be

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

Make sure you have also added the `bootstrap.min.js` script file.

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nKYnY/)**

Comment: Thank you, the data-targer has to have the #, while the id on the div.collapse does not.